# Single column families in phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am recently learning apache phoenix on top of hbase. I am creating table in phoenix. In this I found that phoenix is not creating multiple column families instead it is using single column family with name '0'. Does this hamper the performance of hbase ?

Answer (score 1):

Column families are an optimization based on data access patterns. Only you as the designer know how to group columns into families. Whether you are using HBase or Phoenix on HBase, you need to specify column families when you create the table (if you are using dynamic columns in Phoenix, you can specify the column at query-time rather than table creation).